# mysqldump ask for password even thou given on commandline/config-file

Tags: backup, mysql

I am in the process of migrating my MySQL installation to Amazon RDS and they run MySQL Server version 5.6.12.
I got the client tools of version 5.6.13 and trying to use mysqldump for automated backups.

I always get the question to enter password which block my scripting of backups.

I looks like this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-48-203-112:~$ mysqldump --user=dbadmin -pmysecretpassword -h someserver.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p skygd > dump.sql
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Enter password:
```

I have tried with a configuration file .my.cnf

```
[client]
user=dbadmin
password=mysecretpassword
```

And it is picked up ok, if I run:

```
mysqldump would have been started with the following arguments: --port=3306 --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --quick --quote-names --max_allowed_packet=16M --user=dbadmin --password=mysecretpassword
```

But still same question about enter password.

Are there a bug in 5.6.13 that doesn't allow automated login with password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysqldump --user=dbadmin --password=mysecretpassword -h someserver.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com skygd > dump.sql
```

you typed `-p` at the end of the line

Comment: Total failure of brain today, thanks for pointing out something I should have seen!

Answer (score 0):

It is a better option to mention mysql password at the end of the first command.

**mysqldump -uUsername -p"space-here"Databasename -h"space-here" Hostname >xyz.sql**

And for database import use

mysql -uUsername -p"space-here"Databasename -h"space-here"Hostname